# Spring @Component available before @PostConstruct is completed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.3 for a REST application. I've a weird situation.

I've this interface:

```
public interface ConnectionPoolManager {

    public Connection getConnection(@NotNull String tenantId, boolean longTask);

    public DataSource getDataSource(@NotNull String tenantId, boolean longTask);
}
```

and its implementation:

```
@Component
@Profile({"prod"})
public class ConnectionPoolManagerImpl implements ConnectionPoolManager {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    private Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSource>();


    private Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceLongConnectionsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataSource>();

    private Map<String, String> tenantDatabaseInstanceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    @Autowired
    private TenantRestClient tenantRestClient;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncrypt passwordEncrypt;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource primaryDataSource;

    /**
     * At application startup we cache connection to all DB instances
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            log.info("Caching datasource connections...");
            Set<String> databaseIds = tenantRestClient.findDatabaseInstanceIds();
            //Creating datasource and caching them for later
            databaseIds.forEach(s -> getLocalCache(false).put(s, createDataSource(s, false)));
            databaseIds.forEach(s -> getLocalCache(true).put(s, createDataSource(s, true)));
            log.info("Cached {} datasources", dataSourceMap.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Error trying to cache datasources.", e);
        }
    }
```

In this class I call `tenantRestClient.findDatabaseInstanceIds()` and there I've the problem.

```
@Component
public class TenantRestClient {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.debug("------------INIT--------");
        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
        log.debug("Post construct {} - {}", restTemplateBuilder, restTemplate);
        log.debug("------------INIT COMPLETED --------");
    }

  public Set<String> findDatabaseInstanceIds() {
           //my logic here

            ResponseEntity<Set<String>> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<String>>() {
            });

        }
    }
```

In fact the method findDatabaseInstanceIds() is called before the init() is called. Of course then I've a NullPointerException because restTemplate is null.
How is possible the bean `tenantRestClient` is ready and a method can be called before the init() method is called?

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a Configuration class with a RestTemplate bean and Autowire that to your class.

```
@Configuration
public class Config



@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
  return restTemplateBuilder.build();

}
```

This will create the restTemplate bean for your project. If you need more than one RestTemplate look at @Qualifier.
Now you can autowire  RestTemplate in your class.  No need for PostConstruct

```
@Component
public class TenantRestClient {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Set<String> findDatabaseInstanceIds() {
           //my logic here

            ResponseEntity<Set<String>> response = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Set<String>>() {
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can take help of @DependsOn  annotation, which let's you control the bean creation order

[spring @DependsOn](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

You can mark the dependent bean class  i.e. 
ConnectionPoolManagerImpl with @DependsOn